# How to parse network hostname + port in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qtcore, qurl

I am currently writing a network application in Qt and need to seperate network adresses in the form:

```
example.org:1234
```

into seperate hostname and port QStrings.

Is there a Qt function to easily parse this and check if the given input is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read `QUrl` documentation? `QUrl::host()`, `QUrl::port()`.

Comment: Thaks, just one more question: how do I use QUrl without a presceding scheme (i.i. `http` `ftp`) and so forth?

Comment: @LocalToast: did the answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite simple; you just use the `QUrl` class for this with the [constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#QUrl-3), [host()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#host) and [port()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#port) methods as follows:

```
QUrl url("http://example.org:1234")
qDebug() << "Host:" << url.host();
qDebug() << "Port:" << url.port();
```

As for your comment for avoiding the scheme usage in each url, [you could use this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qurl.html#setScheme):

```
url.setScheme("ftp");
```

or

```
url.setScheme("http");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the [QUrl::fromUserInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromUserInput) function to parse the string, and then the [host](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#host) and [port](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#port) methods of the QUrl object to get the QStrings that you want.

```
auto url{ QUrl::fromUserInput(address) };
auto host{ url.host() };
auto port{ QString::number(url.port()) };
```